# C# Web API Call Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using the C# wrapper HaloEzAPI

When I make a call using GetCustomPostGameCarnageReport I get the following error message.

It wasnt happening two days ago and just suddenly started.

It says the error occurs on line 56 below.
If anyone could help me with this it would be appreciated greatly.

```
Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.
Parameter name: millisecondsTimeoutDescription: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.
Parameter name: millisecondsTimeout
Source Error:
Line 54: if (results.Id.MatchId != null)
Line 55: {
Line 56: var carnageReports = await _service.GetCustomPostGameCarnageReport(results.Id.MatchId);
```

I also get this error occasionally

```
JSON integer 4294967295 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'TeamStats[0].Score', line 1, position 2413.Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: JSON integer 4294967295 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'TeamStats[0].Score', line 1, position 2413.
Source Error:
Line 54: if (results.Id.MatchId != null)
Line 55: {
Line 56: var carnageReports = await _service.GetCustomPostGameCarnageReport(results.Id.MatchId);
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the value of results.Id.MatchId is? You may be passing in some value that is too large for the function to support. I don't know this library but I would start there.

Comment: For the second error: The max value of Int32 is '2147483647'. '4294967295' is actually the max-value of UInt32. So you need to change the Type of the 'Score' property from int to either uint or long.

Comment: The MatchId is actually a GUID, it must convert it to an Int32 when its to big?

Comment: I cant change it because that the call to the api?

Comment: Looking at the api code it seems to convert the matchid to string before processing the request

Comment: Yeah the matchid isn't the problem. Is there some millisecondsTimeout value that you should be setting in your config file? Or is there a settings-object that you can pass when creating _service which has a millisecondsTimeout property?

Comment: I search for millisecondsTimeout in the API project and I couldnt find any references to it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to errors that you provide:

- second error description says very clear: value that json serialized tries to serialize **as an integer** is too big for it. Actually, in your `TeamStats[0].Score` at the time of error occured you have value `4294967295`, but max int value in .net is `2147483647`. So maybe it's better to use `long` instead of `int` (and even more instead of `uint` for not to be outside of its max value if you really have so big values);
- in my opinion, error from the first description is possibly related to the same problem with the `int` max value. If it's possible to post more detailed stack trace of you timeout problem so we can try to dive deeper with it and help you